# How to dynamically assign a value to the commandName attribute in <form:form> tag of spring

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, jstl, modelattribute

I want to dynamically add a string value to the commandName attribute using the following *JSTL* code.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test='${catalogueEntry==null}'>
     add_item
     </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
     update_item
     </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Looks like the spring is interpreting the whole code as a string value instead of assigning the value 'add_item' or 'update_item'.
I tried using the javascript code as well but figured out it is giving the same error as it is client side technology.
Can anyone show me where my problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make use of [EL ternary operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html). In your case code can be written as:

```
<form:form  method="post" commandName="${(catalogueEntry==null) ? 'add_item' : 'update_item'}">
    ...
</form:form>
```